# Create Prolog 2d list filled with 0

Tags: prolog

I would like to ask for some help to create a 2d list in Prolog.

```
matrix(N, M, MX) :- ... //TODO
```

```
?- matrix(2, 3, Mx).
Mx = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] ? ; 
no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `length/2` and `maplist/2`as follows:

```
matrix(Nrows, Ncols, Matrix) :-
    length(Matrix, Nrows), 
    length(Row, Ncols), 
    maplist(=(0), Row), 
    maplist(=(Row), Matrix).
```

Using [`length/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2) you can create a list of *n* variables:

```
?- length(Row, 3).
Row = [_28380, _28386, _28392].
```

Using [`maplist/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2), you can instantiate each element of a list of variables to a desired value:

```
?- length(Row, 3), maplist(=(0), Row).
Row = [0, 0, 0].
```

Once you have created a row, you can create a matrix:

```
?- length(Row, 3), maplist(=(0), Row), length(Matrix, 2), maplist(=(Row), Matrix).
Row = [0, 0, 0],
Matrix = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]].
```

Example:

```
?- matrix(2, 3, M).
M = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]].
```